# How do I convert a list of Option<T> to a list of T when T cannot be copied?

Tags: iterator, rust, option-type

How do I take a `Vec<Option<T>>`, where `T` cannot be copied, and unwrap all the `Some` values?

I run into an error in the `map` step. I'm happy to move ownership of the original list and "throw away" the `None`s.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Uncopyable {
    val: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let num_opts: Vec<Option<Uncopyable>> = vec![
        Some(Uncopyable { val: 1 }),
        Some(Uncopyable { val: 2 }),
        None,
        Some(Uncopyable { val: 4 }),
    ];

    let nums: Vec<Uncopyable> = num_opts
        .iter()
        .filter(|x| x.is_some())
        .map(|&x| x.unwrap())
        .collect();
    println!("nums: {:?}", nums);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=61e0b944a4930451d4f6501f3ff966ce)

Which gives the error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:17:15
   |
17 |         .map(|&x| x.unwrap())
   |               ^-
   |               ||
   |               |hint: to prevent move, use `ref x` or `ref mut x`
   |               cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Rust, when you need a value, you generally want to *move* the elements or *clone* them.

Since move is more general, here [it is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7616e2e8426d9fb6fc44&version=stable), only two changes are necessary:

```
let nums: Vec<Uncopyable> = num_opts
    .into_iter()
//  ^~~~~~~~~~~~-------------- Consume vector, and iterate by value
    .filter(|x| x.is_some())
    .map(|x| x.unwrap())
//       ^~~------------------ Take by value
    .collect();
```

As [llogiq points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30588756/155423), `filter_map` is specialized to filter out `None` already:

```
let nums: Vec<Uncopyable> = num_opts
    .into_iter()
//  ^~~~~~~~~~~~-------- Consume vector, and iterate by value
    .filter_map(|x| x)
//              ^~~----- Take by value
    .collect();
```

And then it works (consuming `num_opts`).

As pointed out by [@nirvana-msu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5540279/nirvana-msu), in Rust 1.33 [`std::convert::identity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/fn.identity.html) was added which can be used instead of `|x| x`. From the documentation:

> ```
> let filtered = iter.filter_map(identity).collect::<Vec<_>>();
> ```

Comment: That's even better than my solution (unless you want to keep the original vector – you cannot have both). Note that you can still use `filter_map` to make it shorter

Comment: @llogiq: It's unclear to me whether Uncopyable also means non-Clone; so maybe the OP would accept a solution which uses `.cloned()`. Thanks for the nifty `filter_map`.

Comment: You could also use [`identity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/fn.identity.html) in place of `|x| x`. There is even example in the docs covering this exact use-case.

Comment: what about `flat_map`?

Comment: @ecoe: I have no idea what you are asking about... I encourage you to ask a question of its own, with full details.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to copy the `Uncopyable` at all, if you are OK with using a `Vec` of references into the original `Vec`:

```
let nums: Vec<&Uncopyable> = num_opts.iter().filter_map(|x| x.as_ref()).collect();
//            ^ notice the & before Uncopyable?
```

This may not do the trick for you if you have to work with an API that requires `&[Uncopyable]`. In that case, use [Matthieu M.'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30590082/155423) which can be reduced to:

```
let nums: Vec<Uncopyable> = num_opts.into_iter().filter_map(|x| x).collect();
```